# Pass Argument to Named Iteratee in Underscore .each

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

In Underscore [_.each](http://underscorejs.org/#each), is there any way to use a named function as the iteratee and pass it an argument?

```
parseItems: function() {
  return _.each(this.items, this.parseItem(item), this);
}
```

Or do I have to do it like this:

```
parseItems: function() {
  return _.each(this.items, function(item) {
    this.parseItem(item);
  }, this);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you just pass the function without invoking it:

```
parseItems: function() {
  return _.each(this.items, this.parseItem, this);
}
```